# PHP - Not give result when do many processing task

Tags: php, processing

I'm working on mining tweets using some text processing (with PHP) like removing html tags, mention / username, link, non-alphanumeric, repeating syllable n character, noise word

When I get search results and directly perform all processing mentioned above, my app does not give resulti. The app just can show results when do processing on 
removing tag html, mentions, links, nonalphanum, n repeating character (not all textprocessing steps).

I want to ask why that in problems come, is PHP code has specific criteria in the process?
In PHP, is it possible to define order time text to be longer processing ? (so I can use all my process step)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

---

I add all preprocessing line of codes. hope you can analyze if there any problem guys. Thanks

```
 function addspaces($value){
    return " ".$value." ";      }
    function containsTLD($string) {
      preg_match(
        "/(AC($|\/)|\.AD($|\/)|\.AE($|\/)|\.AERO($|\/)|\.AF($|\/)|\.AG($|\/)|\.AI($|\/)|\.AL($|\/)|\.AM($|\/)|\.AN($|\/)|\.AO($|\/)|\.AQ($|\/)|\.AR($|\/)|\.ARPA($|\/)|\.AS($|\/)|\.ASIA($|\/)|\.AT($|\/)|\.AU($|\/)|\.AW($|\/)|\.AX($|\/)|\.AZ($|\/)|\.BA($|\/)|\.BB($|\/)|\.BD($|\/)|\.BE($|\/)|\.BF($|\/)|\.BG($|\/)|\.BH($|\/)|\.BI($|\/)|\.BIZ($|\/)|\.BJ($|\/)|\.BM($|\/)|\.BN($|\/)|\.BO($|\/)|\.BR($|\/)|\.BS($|\/)|\.BT($|\/)|\.BV($|\/)|\.BW($|\/)|\.BY($|\/)|\.BZ($|\/)|\.CA($|\/)|\.CAT($|\/)|\.CC($|\/)|\.CD($|\/)|\.CF($|\/)|\.CG($|\/)|\.CH($|\/)|\.CI($|\/)|\.CK($|\/)|\.CL($|\/)|\.CM($|\/)|\.CN($|\/)|\.CO($|\/)|\.COM($|\/)|\.COOP($|\/)|\.CR($|\/)|\.CU($|\/)|\.CV($|\/)|\.CX($|\/)|\.CY($|\/)|\.CZ($|\/)|\.DE($|\/)|\.DJ($|\/)|\.DK($|\/)|\.DM($|\/)|\.DO($|\/)|\.DZ($|\/)|\.EC($|\/)|\.EDU($|\/)|\.EE($|\/)|\.EG($|\/)|\.ER($|\/)|\.ES($|\/)|\.ET($|\/)|\.EU($|\/)|\.FI($|\/)|\.FJ($|\/)|\.FK($|\/)|\.FM($|\/)|\.FO($|\/)|\.FR($|\/)|\.GA($|\/)|\.GB($|\/)|\.GD($|\/)|\.GE($|\/)|\.GF($|\/)|\.GG($|\/)|\.GH($|\/)|\.GI($|\/)|\.GL($|\/)|\.GM($|\/)|\.GN($|\/)|\.GOV($|\/)|\.GP($|\/)|\.GQ($|\/)|\.GR($|\/)|\.GS($|\/)|\.GT($|\/)|\.GU($|\/)|\.GW($|\/)|\.GY($|\/)|\.HK($|\/)|\.HM($|\/)|\.HN($|\/)|\.HR($|\/)|\.HT($|\/)|\.HU($|\/)|\.ID($|\/)|\.IE($|\/)|\.IL($|\/)|\.IM($|\/)|\.IN($|\/)|\.INFO($|\/)|\.INT($|\/)|\.IO($|\/)|\.IQ($|\/)|\.IR($|\/)|\.IS($|\/)|\.IT($|\/)|\.JE($|\/)|\.JM($|\/)|\.JO($|\/)|\.JOBS($|\/)|\.JP($|\/)|\.KE($|\/)|\.KG($|\/)|\.KH($|\/)|\.KI($|\/)|\.KM($|\/)|\.KN($|\/)|\.KP($|\/)|\.KR($|\/)|\.KW($|\/)|\.KY($|\/)|\.KZ($|\/)|\.LA($|\/)|\.LB($|\/)|\.LC($|\/)|\.LI($|\/)|\.LK($|\/)|\.LR($|\/)|\.LS($|\/)|\.LT($|\/)|\.LU($|\/)|\.LV($|\/)|\.LY($|\/)|\.MA($|\/)|\.MC($|\/)|\.MD($|\/)|\.ME($|\/)|\.MG($|\/)|\.MH($|\/)|\.MIL($|\/)|\.MK($|\/)|\.ML($|\/)|\.MM($|\/)|\.MN($|\/)|\.MO($|\/)|\.MOBI($|\/)|\.MP($|\/)|\.MQ($|\/)|\.MR($|\/)|\.MS($|\/)|\.MT($|\/)|\.MU($|\/)|\.MUSEUM($|\/)|\.MV($|\/)|\.MW($|\/)|\.MX($|\/)|\.MY($|\/)|\.MZ($|\/)|\.NA($|\/)|\.NAME($|\/)|\.NC($|\/)|\.NE($|\/)|\.NET($|\/)|\.NF($|\/)|\.NG($|\/)|\.NI($|\/)|\.NL($|\/)|\.NO($|\/)|\.NP($|\/)|\.NR($|\/)|\.NU($|\/)|\.NZ($|\/)|\.OM($|\/)|\.ORG($|\/)|\.PA($|\/)|\.PE($|\/)|\.PF($|\/)|\.PG($|\/)|\.PH($|\/)|\.PK($|\/)|\.PL($|\/)|\.PM($|\/)|\.PN($|\/)|\.PR($|\/)|\.PRO($|\/)|\.PS($|\/)|\.PT($|\/)|\.PW($|\/)|\.PY($|\/)|\.QA($|\/)|\.RE($|\/)|\.RO($|\/)|\.RS($|\/)|\.RU($|\/)|\.RW($|\/)|\.SA($|\/)|\.SB($|\/)|\.SC($|\/)|\.SD($|\/)|\.SE($|\/)|\.SG($|\/)|\.SH($|\/)|\.SI($|\/)|\.SJ($|\/)|\.SK($|\/)|\.SL($|\/)|\.SM($|\/)|\.SN($|\/)|\.SO($|\/)|\.SR($|\/)|\.ST($|\/)|\.SU($|\/)|\.SV($|\/)|\.SY($|\/)|\.SZ($|\/)|\.TC($|\/)|\.TD($|\/)|\.TEL($|\/)|\.TF($|\/)|\.TG($|\/)|\.TH($|\/)|\.TJ($|\/)|\.TK($|\/)|\.TL($|\/)|\.TM($|\/)|\.TN($|\/)|\.TO($|\/)|\.TP($|\/)|\.TR($|\/)|\.TRAVEL($|\/)|\.TT($|\/)|\.TV($|\/)|\.TW($|\/)|\.TZ($|\/)|\.UA($|\/)|\.UG($|\/)|\.UK($|\/)|\.US($|\/)|\.UY($|\/)|\.UZ($|\/)|\.VA($|\/)|\.VC($|\/)|\.VE($|\/)|\.VG($|\/)|\.VI($|\/)|\.VN($|\/)|\.VU($|\/)|\.WF($|\/)|\.WS($|\/)|\.XN--0ZWM56D($|\/)|\.XN--11B5BS3A9AJ6G($|\/)|\.XN--80AKHBYKNJ4F($|\/)|\.XN--9T4B11YI5A($|\/)|\.XN--DEBA0AD($|\/)|\.XN--G6W251D($|\/)|\.XN--HGBK6AJ7F53BBA($|\/)|\.XN--HLCJ6AYA9ESC7A($|\/)|\.XN--JXALPDLP($|\/)|\.XN--KGBECHTV($|\/)|\.XN--ZCKZAH($|\/)|\.YE($|\/)|\.YT($|\/)|\.YU($|\/)|\.ZA($|\/)|\.ZM($|\/)|\.ZW)/i",
        $string,
        $M);
      $has_tld = (count($M) > 0) ? true : false;
      return $has_tld;
    }
    function cleaner($url) {
      $U = explode(' ',$url);
      $W =array();
      foreach ($U as $k => $u) {
        if (stristr($u,".")) {  
          if (containsTLD($u) === true) {
          unset($U[$k]);
          return cleaner( implode(' ',$U));
                }      
            }
        }
      return implode(' ',$U);
    }

    $regexmention = "/(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z-_\.]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)/i";
    $reject = strtolower(implode(" ",file("file.txt")));//bikin deretan kata yg direject, mis: smartfren ga iya gue gw
    $rejectarray = array_map('addspaces',explode(" ", $reject) );

    $removehtmltag=strip_tags($tweet,"");
    $removemention=strtolower(preg_replace($regexmention, "",$removehtmltag));    
    $removeurl=cleaner($removemention);
    $removenonalfa = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", " ",$removeurl );
    $removerepeatchar = preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", $removerepeatchar); 
    $removedigit = preg_replace('/\d/', " ", preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", $removerepeatchar));   
    $removerepeatword = implode(' ',array_unique(preg_split('/[\s?:;,.]+/',   $removedigit, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
    $removedoublesyllable=preg_replace("/(.*)(\\1+)/", "", $removerepeatword ); //wkwk hahaha
    $removeminimumthreechar = preg_replace("/\b\w{1,3}\b/", " ", $removedoublesyllable);
    $removenoiseword = addspaces( $removeminimumthreechar ); // " saya ... bb "
    $final=trim( str_replace($rejectarray, " ",$removenoiseword) );
//say
echo $final;
```

---

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are passing the maximum time allowed by the web server

Try to use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Or using too much memory, in this case modify php.ini memory_limit to something reasonable for your case like

```
memory_limit = 128M
```